# See When Text Changes Div Size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div, a container to some content, that changes size to be able to fit the text inside it. I want the div's size to stay static.

I'm changing this content dynamically, and I want to be able to know when the text is too big to fit inside the container, and to cut out the part of the the text that's making the container grow.

Something like this:

[image]

Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you don't need Javascript for that but you can solve it with only CSS. Give your container a fixed height and hide the overflow:

```css
div {
  line-height: 1em;
  height: 2em;
  width: 10em;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  bla bla bla<br />
  bla bla bla
</div>

<div>
  Oh no<br />
  The container changed
  its size to fix the text!
  I've got to get rid some
  of this annoying text
</div>
```

Comment: The thing is that if I hide some of the text inside a div by hiding the overflow, I won't have access to the part that's making it big.

I haven't mentioned it, but that's something that I want to do. I want to save extra piece of text.

Comment: What do you want to do with the overflowing text? Maybe try `overflow: auto`. Then scrollbars will appear if the text overflows.

Comment: I want to save it and put it aside.

Display the text that isn't overflowing and save the rest that is.

Comment: And then what? Where do you reuse it? Pleas explain some more.

Comment: I want to take some paragraphs of things I write and display them in different colors in a box.
When I click a button, another box appears, of the same size, with more of the text.

The colors would be in grading, so you'd have a colorful, rainbow-like set of boxes with each containing a small bit of the text, being displayed one after another at the press of a button.

But don't mind all that, it's not relevant. I've already got the boxes showing and etc. I just want to know how I can handle the overflowing text.

Answer (score 1):

Use Css `text-overflow:`

**For example:**

`text-overflow: clip;` would clip the word at containers end

`text-overflow: ellipsis;` would enter '...' after the last visible charakter.

[HERE](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-overflow/) is a nice Demo...

Answer (score 1):

There's no listener to size change. You can set an interval that checks the height (example below). Or even better: perform the check when you update the text!

```js
setInterval(function() {
  if ($('#the-container').height() > 42) {
    // do something with container
  }
}, 50); // Can change time to whatever floats your boat
```

Code not tested, but I think you get the point.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.You can fix height of div or container and make overflow-y auto;

fiddle demo:

```css
.static{
    overflow-y:auto;
    height:100px;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    width:200px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
.right{float:right}
.left{float:left}
```

```html
<div class="static left">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>


<div class="static right">esse cillum dolore eu fugiat </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/DhwaniSanghvi/31hryaw2/